# Qt hide QLayout (switch between two layouts)

Tags: qt, layout

I didn't find solution for my problem with two `QLayouts`. I need app with `QHBoxLayout` with possible expandind when I will add new widgets, push buttons, ....
So what I have: One `QDialog` and two layouts. Now I know that I can't hide the layout. 
So I tray just :

```
layout()->removeItem(firstlayout);
layout()->addLayout(secondLayout);
```

But when I did this, I saw all items in first layout on possition [0,0].
So next step I try:

```
for (all items in first layout) if (widget) widget->hide();
```

But this is working only with `QWidget` and I have many different items in layouts.

Simply way is use the widget, because there is possible to use hide/show, but I need auto expanding window when I add new items.

Answer (score 1):

Just rebuild the layout, there is no need to keep the two layouts in existence at the same time. Probably clearest is to have two (or more) methods, which first delete current layout, then create new layout, add widgets to it, hide all widgets you want hidden, and set it as current layout. Note that you don't even need to keep a member variable for the layout, since QWidget has that anyway and provides you with setter and getter.

Or, if you have different widgets in different layouts, and actually want to be able "switch pages" so to say, simply use [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.digia.com/latest/qstackedwidget.html). Or if you have a fixed part (buttons etc), and then part with "pages", then put the "pages" into QStackedWidget, and keep fixed part out of it.

Comment: Ok QStakedWidget is ok, but if I will add to this widget QVBoxLayout and into this layout many buttons. Will the QStakedWidget expand according expanding QVBoxLayout (when button has set fix height)?

Answer (score 0):

'addLayout(secondLayout/firstLayout) ' will remove the other layout automatically, you do not have to remove it. If you keep a pointer to the layout(which has addWidget() before), you can simply use the layout and widgets in it later. :)

Comment: But this is only for swith the layouts, it does not hide all widget in not used layout, does it?

Comment: It does. Have  you tried it? :) I use qt a lot recently. . :)